# Bizarre interrmitent redirect problems with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Using `curl -I` to check the headers, I'm finding that some pages on my site do a redirect for no apparent reason. One page, `/sample` gives a 301 to `/sample/` every **third** time it is requested, without any reference to it in .htaccess.

A page that is redirected with `RewriteRule ^sample2.htm /sample2 [NC,R,L]` gives a 302 except on the 4-5th request, it returns `sample.htm` instead of the redirect.

Apache is 2.2

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this was caused by a duplicate .htaccess file called `.htaccess copy`.